# jquery json empty control

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkbox

I have a table with checkboxes, and I am posting it by clicking `<a id='fecth_details'...` as:

```
  $('#fetch_details').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = { 'selected_sales[]' : []};
    $("input[name='salesID[]']:checked").each(function() {
      data['selected_sales[]'].push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#list_data').html('');
    $.post('fetch_sales_details',data,function (data) { $('#list_data').html(data)});
  });
```

I need to control it if it is empty or not. Basically testing like:

```
var data = ({ 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });
alert(data);
if ($.isEmptyObject(data.choices))
{
   alert('it is an empty object');
}
else
{
    alert('auch! I am not empty');
}
```

But not working... I shouldn't work if no checkbox is checked.

Comment: Probably should also use a different name for the callback "result" data - reusing the same variable name might cause unexpected results in the callback code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
   $('#fetch_details').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      if(!$(":checkbox:checked").length>0){//atleast one checkbox is checked
        //your code here
        //
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this;

```
  var data = { 'choices' : { "" : ["Jon", "Susan"] } };
  alert(data);
  if ($.isEmptyObject(data.choices)) {
    alert('it is an empty object');
  } else {
    alert('auch! I am not empty');
  }
```

Or leaving your code as it was, with just a little modification;

```
  var data = { 'choices' : ["Jon", "Susan"] };
  alert(data);
  if ($.isEmptyObject(data.choices)) {
    alert('it is an empty object');
  } else {
    alert('auch! I am not empty');
  }
```